# JQ Array Overflows CSV Column

Tags: json, csv, jq

I need to pull a list of AWS instances with their instance ID and public IP, and outputting that to a spread sheet in csv format.

Here is the [ORIGINAL JSON](https://pastebin.com/SiNbVgkq) I am working with (external IP info has been obscured).

This is the command I'm using:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --profile="$aws_account"  | jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[] | [ .InstanceId,  .NetworkInterfaces[].PrivateIpAddresses[].Association.PublicIp // null] | @csv'
```

This works! But a problem happens if there is more than one public IP.

With one public ip the output looks good:

```
AWS Instance ID    | Public IP
i-0e636f1d0f0009f78,18.xxx.xx.112
```

With more than one public IP the output overflows the columns in the CSV spread sheeet:

```
   AWS Instance ID | Public IP     |Key Name    Owner     Instance State

   i-9a02a66b      ,54.xx.xx.201,52.x.xxxx.160,52.x.xx.175,34.xx.xx.31
```

I would like to know how to use the JQ command to replace the commas with spaces (so csv can fit them in the same column) and also replace null values with a space (for aws instances with no public IP).

I am leaving out the code that creates the extra columns so we can focus on the public IPs which is the biggest problem.

Comment: Yeah that's the way it works without the `@csv` option. If you output to `@csv`, then all the entries are surrounded by quotes, even if the -r is there. So I'm using sed to remove the quotes that are still there because we're outputting to csv.

Comment: Have you considered using TSV instead of CSV?

Comment: But the quotes **are part of the csv format**. That's a feature, not a bug. If the code that's parsing your output doesn't understand those quotes, it isn't really a compliant CSV parser (and the format you want isn't really CSV).

Comment: No, I haven't tried using TSV. I just don't want quotes in the spread sheet that I'm putting out to. I was only using CSV as a 'sread sheet friendly' format.

Comment: Open your CSV in Excel (or otherwise your spreadsheet of choice), without modifying it with `sed` first. You won't see the quotes there as literal data; they're *syntax*, not semantics.

Comment: Ah, ok. Gotcha. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `sed` to remove quotes. The quotes are not just *important*, they're **critical**.

Consider the following example:

```
jq -Rnr '[inputs] | @csv' <<EOF
first item
second item,has,commas
third item
EOF
```

That code emits a single line, **which is in fact a valid 3-cell CSV**:

```
"first item","second item,has,commas","third item"
```

See how the commas that are data are inside quotes, whereas the commas that are syntax are outside them? This is a critical element of CSV syntax.

---

It's only when you get rid of the quotes protecting those commas that you end up with:

```
first item,second item,has,commas,third item
```

...where the data is parsed as 5 cells instead of 3.

---

To actually ensure that your IP addresses are passed to `@csv` as a single field, you may want to join them ahead-of-time; that might be something like:

```
jq -r '
  .Reservations[].Instances[]
  | [ .InstanceId,
      ([.NetworkInterfaces[].PrivateIpAddresses[].Association.PublicIp // null
       ] | join(","))
    ] | @csv'
```

This still has commas between the IPs, but those commas will be **inside quotes**, and thus treated as data within a field -- rather than a split between two fields -- by a compliant parser.

Comment: Thanks. When I use my line without sed: `aws ec2 describe-instances --profile=company-prod   | jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[] | [ .InstanceId,  .NetworkInterfaces[].PrivateIpAddresses[].Association.PublicIp // null ] | @csv' It still outputs the public IPs with commas between each one. So it's still overflowing the spread sheet columns: `"i-9a123466b","54.xx.xx.201","52.x.xx.160","52.x.xx.175","34.xx.xx.31"`

Comment: Can you provide JSON that someone without an EC2 account can use to repro/test? Basically, you need to make sure that your IPs are in a single field, rather than being treated as a sequence by JQ. Can't test a change to the JQ code without being able to run it, can't run it without JSON that acts as input.

Comment: Sure! I'll have that momentarily. Thank you very much!

Comment: Added a draft of a change intended to address the issue, but it's untested until that data is available. :)

Comment: Hah. Ok cool. Really appreciate that. I just have to take a moment to sanitize the json output. I'll get hit hard at work if security scans the internet and finds IPs etc belonning to the company hanging out on the internet. :)

Comment: Hi sorry for the delay. Here is the json I'm trying to parse using jq. I just removed external ip and dns. Otherwise it's the exact json I'm using: [AWS JSON](https://pastebin.com/SiNbVgkq). Thanks.

Comment: For future note, btw -- pastebin has a history of being pretty awful to people without adblockers (they've switched to a more reputable ad service more recently, but they used to be full of animated ads -- and I've always considered anyone willing to host those probably not above JavaScript malware). You might consider https://ix.io/, https://gist.github.com/, or other alternatives going forward.

Comment: ...anyhow, the answer has now been tuned/tested with the data provided.

Comment: Oh wow. Nice man. Thank you! I will test that out. And yes, noted about using gist or ix.io going forward. I'll use those to make things easier going forward. I will let you know if I have any other questions or if I get it working.